# How to understand Bhagwat Gita?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita

Every time I try to read Bhagwat Gita I feel confused. It feels like I have to follow life with restrictions. Like we can't have the desire, should not think of the result, wrong to have the material desire. Could you tell me how can I understand Gita?

Comment: You can read a Bhashya by Adi Shankaracharya called Shankara Bhashya. Bhagavad Gita doesn’t restrict anyone. It’s just that if you perform an action, there is a consequence that follows. The chapter talking about not thinking of the result - talks of karmayoga i.e. for anyone who wants moksha, he must perform actions thinking about the Lord and not have any desire for fruits. If he has desire for fruits, the Lord will grant his desire and in order to get his fruits he will have to take birth again, etc. Having a worthy guru would be a good start for understanding better

Comment: The target audience for the bhagavad gita are male dvijas who are seekers of moksha. It gives the instructions for performing bhakti, jnana, and karma yoga, which are the means for moksha. So, instructions like "abandon all sense pleasures", etc. are for them and not for any reader of the gita.

Comment: @Ikshvaku how can we conclude that it is only for male dvijas? Isn’t it for everyone?

Comment: @Archit Because the paths of bhakti, karma, and jnana yoga require conducting vedic yajnas and meditating on the upanishads, and only male dvijas have the qualification for those things, because only they have the qualification for vedic study. But there is still lots of practical knowledge and actions everyone can follow in the gita, like living a sattvic lifestyle, offering food to krishna and eating only prasadam, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku so what should I do just read Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: The gita is a set of instructions. If you cannot follow then you should rethink Hinduism.

Comment: Gita is for general peoplw only since vedas and upanishad are for brahmin Krishna wanted to condense and give message of all the veda Sahara which were not in accessi to sutras and strees to them if stated by ishvakhu please correct you reach that epitome of perfection with gita itself

Comment: It's not thinking result or goal it's not hankering on the goal on should work towards goal like if try Iit jee someone didn't get it after putting and yardwork then one should not commit suicide that is what krishna us saying

Comment: Don't be greedy of the desire desire should be there otherwise why he allowed pandas to construct palace that resembles heaven. They have lost in game of dice but they are not affected by the loss.

Comment: Now 2 doubts are cleared I believe

Answer (score 3):

There are four goals of life according to Hinduism. These goals are dharma, artha (wealth), kama (desire) and moksha. Gita is for those who are fed up with artha and kama and want to attain moksha. Who are the people who want to attain moksha? They are people who think of this world as a vale of sorrow.

**Ocean of Life – Need for Moksha**

> "That Ocean, so terrible has sorrow for its waters. Anxiety and grief
> constitute its deep lakes. Disease and Death are its gigantic
> alligators. The great fears that strike the heart at every step are
> its huge snakes. The deeds inspired by Tamas are its tortoises. Those
> inspired by Rajas are its fishes. Wisdom constitutes the raft for
> crossing it. The affections entertained for objects of the senses are
> its mire. Decrepitude constitutes its region of grief and trouble.
> Knowledge..is its island. Acts constitute its great depth. Truth is
> its shores. Pious observances constitute the verdant weeds floating on
> its bosom. Envy constitutes its rapid and mighty current. The diverse
> sentiments of the heart constitute its mines. The diverse kinds of
> gratification are its valuable gems. Grief and fever are its winds.
> Misery and thirst are its mighty eddies. Painful and fatal diseases
> are its huge elephants. The assemblages of bones are its flight of
> steps and phlegm is its froth. Gifts are its pearl-banks. The lakes of
> blood are its corals. Loud laughter constitutes its roars. Diverse
> sciences are its impassibility. Tears are its brine. Renunciation of
> company constitutes the high refuge (of those that seek to cross it).
> Children and spouses are its unnumbered leeches. Friends and kinsmen
> are the cities and towns on its shores. Abstention from injury and
> Truth are its boundary line. Death is its storm-wave. The knowledge of
> Vedanta is its island (capable of affording refuge to those that are
> tossed upon its waters). Acts of compassion towards all creatures
> constitute its life-buoys, and Emancipation is the priceless commodity
> offered to those voyaging on the waters in search of merchandise. "

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCIII**

If you think that this world is a mansion of mirth and the above passage describing this world a vale of tears is over the top then you should go for artha and kama and Gita which is a moksha sastra is not for you.

Comment: If one wants moksha then one has to control lust, greed and anger and do Jnana Yoga or Bhakti Yoga or Karma Yoga or Raja Yoga.

Comment: There is no quick method. Consult a competent Guru on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one very helpful resource and study material which laid details of various aspects of Bhagavad Gita which intended to use as suppliment material for study of Bhagavad Gita as it is:

https://ebooks.iskcondesiretree.com/pdf/Bhagvad_Gita_Notes_Complete_Gauranga_priya_prabhu/BGNotes%20v3.1.pdf

It will clear many confusions and also help me much.

One caveat: It is not to be read as only but with book of Bhagavad Gita as it is. And sorry if someone is disagree with it.

Jay Shri Krishna